# Read IEnumerable or wait for it to finish changing first

Tags: c#, linq, thread-safety, ienumerable

I want to read a Dictionary in C# and possibly get a list or dictionary from it using linq. My problem is that the list can change at any point when I make the request (ie not thread safe i guess).

Can someone give me a example of how I can do this? Would I need to use lock() ?

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> GetLatest(DateTime since, Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> requestedDict)
{
    Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> returnList = new Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>();
    returnList = requestedDict.Where(x => x.Key > since).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    return returnList;
}
```

This is the exception im getting:

> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a concurrent dictionary.  Locking is implemented for you. And it is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks, does it have identical usage?

Comment: As far as I am aware.

Comment: Well it doesn't have the .Add() method :P Looks like I've got some reading to do! Didn't know these things existed! I wonder if I should just use them everywhere!!

Comment: TryAdd.  TryGet.  You can key it the sameway though.  I don't know if Id use them everywhere! Maybe there is some cost involved in attempting to obtain a lock when it isnt needed.

Comment: Thanks mate, any ideas if I can use a list of some sort instead? ConcurrentList doesnt exist

Comment: What are your specific needs exactly. are you mimicking a queue, stack or a circular queue or anything like that?

Comment: Actually looking at your code snippet, It "looks" like you might benefit from a stack (LIFO) ConcurrentStack<T> with TryPeek. I was going to suggest the C5 generic collection library as another set of collections to look over.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this as an extension method on `IDictionary` and then you can pass in whatever dictionary you want concurrent or otherwise

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<DateTime, T> GetLatest<T>(this IDictionary<DateTime, T> dict, DateTime since)
    {
        var returnList = new Dictionary<DateTime, T>();
        returnList = dict.Where(x => x.Key > since).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
dict.GetLatest(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1));
```

Comment: It's thread safe if you use a ConcurrentDictionary or you can use a normal Dictionary and then use a lock from the place that you use it.